# How to merge two arrays within a variable?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of two arrays that I am trying to merge into one array. My arrays are in a variable `$arr`, `var_dump` of which looks like this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'onetag' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'anothertag' (length=10)
```

Applying `$marr = array_merge($arr)` doesn't appear to do anything. I am trying to get the merged array to look like this `['onetag', 'anothertag']`, or upon `var_dump` like this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'onetag' (length=6)
  1 => string 'anothertag' (length=10)
```

Comment: check implode function

Comment: [how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code

```
$arr = array_column($arr,0);
var_dump($arr);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'onetag' (length=6)
  1 => string 'anothertag' (length=10)
```

Comment: if its working for you then please accept this answer @Arthur Tarasov

Comment: Got it, I had to wait for 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$marr = array_merge($arr[0],$arr[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but what if I do not know exactly how many arrays are in the `$arr` array? There can be from 1 to 10 or 20 arrays. I just used two as an example. How can I set it up then?

Comment: Just wrap it in a foreach loop and merge them consecutively.

Answer (score 1):

`array_merge` takes at least two arrays as arguments and merge them into one. You are passing only one and no second to merge the first with. You want to create a single array with all the element of `$arr[0]` and `$arr[1]`. So you have tomerge `$arr[0]` and `$arr[1]` like so: `array_merge($arr[0],$arr[1]);`

And here is simple foreach loop:

```
$marr = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $marr = array_merge($marr, $arr[$key]);
}
```